# What ArcGIS Desktop license level is needed to use ring map tool/script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, basic-license-level, error-000824

I'm trying to create ring maps with the tool/script found in the link(s) below:

- http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0408/files/ringmaps.pdf
- http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/fall-2013/looking-at-temporal-changes

I have the basic ArcGIS 10.3 license level.  When I try to run the first step of the tool I get:

> ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed"

I'm wondering if anyone has used this and knows if I need the standard/advanced license level or if there is a way around this.

Comment: Looks like the Advanced License for ArcGIS is needed but for QGIS with reference to your links https://github.com/mapplus/qgis-scripts/blob/master/scripts/Create%20Ring%20Maps.py

Comment: A quick look at the scripts inside, the Feature to Polygon tool requires an advanced license. All the other tools inside will run with a Basic license. Without really digging into the workflow I cant offer an alternative tool or suggestion at this time.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KHibma:

> A quick look at the scripts inside, the Feature to Polygon tool
>   requires an advanced license. All the other tools inside will run with
>   a Basic license. Without really digging into the workflow I cant offer
>   an alternative tool or suggestion at this time.